# Created a function but in an if statement the function isn't recognized swift

Tags: ios, swift

I made the function `getLocation()` and used it in an `else{ getLocation()}` which works. Later when I tried to define a new function `locationmanager` the `if...{ getLocation()}` gets the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'getLocation'

I'm not sure if the syntax isn't right or if there's another way to call on the `getLocation` function.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var coreLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationManager: LocationManager!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var location_info: UILabel!
    @IBAction func Update_Location(_ sender: Any) {
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        coreLocationManager.delegate=self
        locationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance

        let authorizationCode = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if authorizationCode == CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined &&
            coreLocationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization))||coreLocationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization)){}
        if Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "NSlocationWhenInUseUsageDescription") != nil{
            coreLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }else{
            getLocation()
        }
    }

    func getLocation(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler{(latitude, longitude, status, verboseMessage, error)->()in
            self.displayLocation(location: CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
        }
    }

    func displayLocation(location:CLLocation){
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center:     CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude),span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)), animated:true)
        let locationPinCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = locationPinCoord

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)

        locationManager.reverseGeocodeLocationWithCoordinates(location) { (reverseGecodeInfo, placemark, error) in
            print(reverseGecodeInfo!)
        }
    }
}

func locationmanager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.denied || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted {
        getLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `getLocation()` is nested in the body of `viewDidLoad()`, so it's available only in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use proper indentation.

Try this, select-all, cut, then paste. Xcode will auto indent for you and you will immediately see that the problem is that you have a `}` in the wrong place.

Comment: That's not it, the problem is that the function is not being recognized as such.

Comment: It is it. I copied and pasted your code so I know. You have other problems as well, but the brace is the reason your `getLocation()` isn't found.

Comment: @Shannon What you are missing is that your `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` delegate method is not inside the class as you can see when your code is indented properly.